# Repositories and transactions

Tags: c#, software-design

In my project I have many repositories. Each repository can work with different database. For example, the AuthRepository works with the ProjectName.Auth database, the SubscriptionsRepository works with the ProjectName.Subscriptions database etc. What if user call method, which using both repositories, and some of them will throw exception? For example:

```
public void SomeMethod(){
    _authRepository.DoSomething();
    _subscriptionsRepository.DoSomething(); <-- error here
}
```

How I can handle that? As I said before, I use many repositories, so I don't know how to use transactions here, because each repository can use different DB.

Comment: Use 1 transaction per call and commit each transaction after all calls have been complete. In the event of an exception roll all transactions back. If you need help with how to use/setup transactions use google and find a tutorial.

Comment: To clarify, is your question how to rollback what you did on the first database? Like a transaction that applies to multiple databases?

Comment: Wrap them in a `TransactionScope`. However, if your databases cross servers, you have to make distributed transactions work, and that can be a huge pain. If you can't use transactions, your only recourse is to write code yourself that can undo things you've done, somehow -- or live with the partial situation and kick it up to a higher authority.

Comment: @Lithium, Yes, it is.

Comment: Alex; I'm not 100% sure of this, but to get you started you might look at Linked Servers. I believe that you make all of your databases appear as if they are part of a single one - thus your repositories could all belong to the same DB - potentially allowing a single transaction. Federated tables come to mind as well. Again, I have only read about this and never set one up so you will want to do your own research.